# Getting Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_GET' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql, parse-error

I am making a page where on page 1 i am fetching data from mysql & on click of the name i am redirecting to another page i.e page 2 where complete details is shown. 
Please Help ! 
Here is the php code of Page 1

```
            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="root"; // Mysql username 
            $password=""; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="testmra"; // Database name 
            // Connect to server and select databse.
            $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name,COUNT(status_id) AS Count from bookingdetails WHERE  YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND status_id='2' GROUP BY name");
            echo "<table border='1' style='border:black;'>
                <tr>
                    <!--<th id='td'>Sr No.</th>-->
                    <th id='td'>Name</th>   
                    <th id='td'>No. of Bookings Done</th>
                </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";

                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'><a href='Details.php'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['Count'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>

Page 2 
<?php

            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="root"; // Mysql username 
            $password=""; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="testmra"; // Database name 
            // Connect to server and select databse.
            $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
            $name=(varchar) $_GET['name'];
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from bookingdetails WHERE  YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND status_id='2' AND name='$name'");
            echo "<table border='1' style='border:black;'>
                <tr>
                    <th id='td'>Room</th>   
                    <th id='td'>Name</th>
                    <th id='td'>Purpose</th>
                    <th id='td'>Attendee</th>
                    <th id='td'>Date</th>
                    <th id='td'>Start Time</th>
                    <th id='td'>End Time</th>
                </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";

                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['room'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['purpose'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['attendee'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['starttime'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['endtime'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Comment: `(varchar) $_GET['name']`?? Are you sure about `varchar` in PHP?

Comment: Why are you typecasting `varchar`?

Comment: The type varchar does not exist in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this following line in page1

```
 echo "<td align='center' id='td'><a href='Details.php'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

to

```
 echo "<td align='center' id='td'><a href='Details.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

and in page 2

```
(varchar) $_GET['name']
```

to

```
$_GET['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such need to typecast `$name=(varchar) $_GET['name'];`

Simply use : `$name= $_GET['name'];`

You also need to add the same param in query string

```
echo "<td align='center' id='td'><a href='Details.php?name=" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `(varchar)` typecast. No need to do that, also `varchar` is a data type in MySQL not PHP.

I'd add some validation to ensure that your `$_GET` is set to prevent undefined index errors which would have been thrown if the typecast wasn't there as your URL was wrong in the first page.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to check if `GET` is set. you can do like this

```
$name=isset($_GET['name'])? $_GET['name'] : '' ;
```

> and check if you are passing `name` in the url by get method .

if you are using this link to come on page 2 .

```
echo "<td align='center' id='td'><a href='Details.php'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

then change this to.  pass name as get method

```
echo "<td align='center' id='td'><a href='Details.php?name=".$row['name']."'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></td>";
```

so your code on page 2 will

```
<?php

            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="root"; // Mysql username 
            $password=""; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="testmra"; // Database name 
            // Connect to server and select databse.
            $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
            $name=isset($_GET['name'])? $_GET['name'] : '' ;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from bookingdetails WHERE  YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND status_id='2' AND name='$name'");
            echo "<table border='1' style='border:black;'>
                <tr>
                    <th id='td'>Room</th>   
                    <th id='td'>Name</th>
                    <th id='td'>Purpose</th>
                    <th id='td'>Attendee</th>
                    <th id='td'>Date</th>
                    <th id='td'>Start Time</th>
                    <th id='td'>End Time</th>
                </tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<tr>";

                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['room'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['purpose'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['attendee'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['starttime'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center' id='td'>" . $row['endtime'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
```

or you should put whole code in a condition like

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
  // your code here 
}
```

Comment: I would explain the ternary operator to the OP, just so they know what it is.